# How to prepopulate a Android Room database?

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am working through several Codelabs to teach myself Android development with **Android Studio 4.0**.
As my first project, I wanted to write a lean app that helps to do quick lookups from tables out of a textbook (about 225 Tables with 21 columns and 50 rows each, the entries are 4 up to 120 chars long).
My questions are:

**Is there an easy ("official") way to get the tables from the pdf/CSV into the database?**
(I would copy-paste the values and write some sort of insertion script.)

**Should I even consider a different data structure e.g. out of Android OS performance reasons?**
(One table will be accessed every few seconds or so.)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate